# Remove item from basket in django oscar

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

How can I remove an item from the customer's basket in django oscar?

The following line just acts as an `<a href="#"></a>` link:

```
<a href="#" data-id="{{ forloop.counter0 }}" data-behaviours="remove" class="inline">{% trans "Remove" %}</a>
```

Comment: Just like you'd do with any Django model instance, using the line's `delete` method: `basket.all_lines().filter(..).delete()`

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Oscar uses some javascript to remove an item from the basket:$('a[data-behaviours~="delete"]').click(function(){o.notifications.checkAndSubmit($(this),'delete');});},checkAndSubmit:function($ele,btn_val){$ele.closest('tr').find('input').attr('checked','checked');$ele.closest('form').find('button[value="'+btn_val+'"]').click();return false;}};

Answer (score 2):

In Python, if you know the line of which item to delete:

```
request.basket.items[line].delete()
request.basket.save()
```

In JavaScript, look at 
https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/oscar/static/oscar/js/oscar/ui.js#L177-180 for the lines of code that trigger the item removal:

```
$('#content_inner').on('click', '#basket_formset a[data-behaviours~="remove"]', function(event) {
    o.basket.checkAndSubmit($(this), 'form', 'DELETE');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Some more possibly helpful reading: [email thread about python deletion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-oscar/vlCTWNnYxcg) and [email thread about js deletion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-oscar/uYjSI8QmVwU/16JnWXCSt58J).